# create_resource breaks parser order during catalogue creation

Tags: puppet

I have a serious problem in Puppet 3.6.2 which I do not understand. I want to use a central account and user management, but things do not work as expected. I am using a type `account` from torrancew-account (https://github.com/torrancew/puppet-account). The accounts themselves are defined via hiera:

```
# common.yaml

accounts:
  puppet:
    ssh_key_type: ssh-rsa
    ssh_key: some_key
    password: password
    create_group: true
  ...
```

The resources (users, groups) are created via `create_resources` in my profile:

```
class profile::accounts {

  create_resources('account', hiera_hash('accounts'))
}
```

Another profile requires that all users and groups are already created.

```
class profile::puppet::master {

  require '::profile::accounts'

  if !defined(User['puppet']) {
    user { 'puppet':
      ensure => present,
    }
  }
}
```

I receive a `Duplicate declaration: User[puppet] is already declared cannot redeclare`.

Can someone explain my why during catalogue creation the resources within `create_resources('account', hiera_hash('accounts'))` are not evaluated immediately after the `profile::accounts` gets parsed?

I have added some debug output and could see that at first `profile::accounts` gets parsed and then `profile::puppet::master` and afterwards the `account` types which actually create all users and groups. This results an a duplicate declaration exception because the user has been created by `profile::puppet::master`. This should only be a fallback and should not happen in my case.

Comment: The parse order is: `profile::accounts` -> `profile::puppet::master` -> `account`. Why? It should be and I expect: `profile::accounts` -> `account` -> `profile::puppet::master`

Comment: What mandates that necessity to have `User['puppet']` already declared when the master profile is being evaluated?

Comment: The reason is that I want to configure the system and not the modules themselves. I try to leave them as "stupid" as possible, leaving setups to the profiles layer and make extensive use of hiera for configuration.

Comment: How about `if ! 'puppet' in keys(hiera('accounts')) { ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ever build parse-order dependent constructs. In fact, try and avoid the `defined` function altogether, and especially the `if !defined(Resource[x]) { resource { x: } }` antipattern.

You are bound to burn yourself just the way it's currently happening. In most cases, you cannot reliably anticipate the parse order.

Take special note that just because you have a (dangerous) call of

```
require '::profile::accounts'
```

in class `profile::puppet::master` before your `if !defined()` call, this does not mean that the required class will be **parsed** before the function is evaluated. The opposite is the case: The compiler will evaluate `profile::puppet::master` first, including the `defined()` query, and only then deal with `::profile::accounts`.

Comment: The main problem that I am dealing with third-party modules e.g. stephenrjohnson/puppetmodule which contains some `!defined(Resource[x])` expressions. Most of the modules do a good job, but in the sense of separating profiles and roles it is very difficult to get things working.

Comment: Have you got any suggestions what is the right approach: Not using third-party modules, build your own "right" version or dealing with the current implementation issues?

Comment: Ok... I try to avoid the `require` statements, but where do I put my ordering dependecies? Should I put them to the role?

Comment: Those modules are [broken IMHO](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/Fvl0aOe4RPE/Ph38bq3FmHcJ). We should move to [alternative designs](https://github.com/ffrank/puppet-constraints). Yes, you might want to fork and fix those modules. - About ordering, that depends on your implementation. Whatever class or resource depends on the accounts profile, you can make that explicit. `Class[::profile::accounts] -> Class[my_dependent_stuff]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will use only explicit dependencies and make all necessary modifications to get rid of these `require` expressions. I will try to move forward. Thanks!